# Use "sed" to reorder two consecutive lines when some criteria is true

Tags: linux, sed

The input text is:

```
Lines_with_no_search_string_1
...,"service_id":222,"...1
...,"service_id":111,"...2
Lines_with_no_search_string_2
...,"service_id":111,"...3
...,"service_id":222,"...4
Lines_with_no_search_string_3
...,"service_id":222,"...5
Lines_with_no_search_string_4
...,"service_id":111,"...6
Lines_with_no_search_string_5
```

Notes:

- "..." is random string that doesn't contain "service_id". (Digits after "..." is just for identifying the line order!)
- "Lines_with_no_search_string" is one or multiple lines that none contains "service_id".
- There are only maximum 2 consecutive lines that contain "service_id", the ones with "111" and "222".

Criteria:

- Lines that don't contain "service_id"

  - Print out (with same line numbers).
- Single line that contains "service_id"

  - If "111", print out as is (with same line number).
  - If "222", print out as is, with a string "NONE" inserted at the beginning of the line (with same line number).
- Two consecutive lines that contain "service_id"

  - If "111" comes first, print out both lines  as is (with same line number).
  - If "222" comes first, print out in reverse order, i.e., first print out "111" and the "222" (with reverse line numbers compare to original).

The desired output is:

```
Lines_with_no_search_string_1
...,"service_id":111,"...2          (*)
...,"service_id":222,"...1          (*)
Lines_with_no_search_string_2
...,"service_id":111,"...3
...,"service_id":222,"...4
Lines_with_no_search_string_3
"NONE"...,"service_id":222,"...5    (*)
Lines_with_no_search_string_4
...,"service_id":111,"...6
Lines_with_no_search_string_5
```

(*) shows lines that have been modified.

The reason I would like to use "sed", is that I have a long command line that has resulted in the above input, and I prefer to continue with pipe ("|") to get the final output.
If there are so called one-liners with other commands than "sed" that give the desired output, I am more than happy to use it.

I have spent many hours on different "sed"-combinations, without getting it right.

My last approach was based on the below code that replaces "\n":

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/some_string/g' # Note: for csh/tcsh, "!" needs to be escaped.
```

And I tried with putting the two consecutive lines (when 222-line is followed by 111-line), in "\1" and "\2", and reverse them:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\(.*[^2][^2][^2]*222.*\)\n\(.*[^1][^1][^1]*111.*\)/\2\n\1/g'
```

But it does not work as I thought:

```
...,"service_id":111,"...6
Lines_with_no_search_string5
Lines_with_no_search_string1
...,"service_id":222,"...1
...,"service_id":111,"...2
Lines_with_no_search_string2
...,"service_id":111,"...3
...,"service_id":222,"...4
Lines_with_no_search_string3
...,"service_id":222,"...5
Lines_with_no_search_string4
```

I have realized now that, the solution that I have based my approach on, goes through the whole file.
And that's the reason behind the garbled output above.

Appreciate if anybody could come up with a solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].  You should provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's simple:

```
sed '
# lines that dont conatin service_id
/service_id/!{
    # Print out (with same line numbers).
    b
}
N;

# single line that contains service_id
/service_id[^\n]*\n[^\n]*service_id/!{
    # If "111", print out as is (with same line number).
    /222/{
       # If "222", print out as is, with a string "NONE" inserted at the beginning of the line
        s/^/NONE/
    }
    b
}

# Two consecutive lines that contain "service_id"
/111[^\n]*\n[^\n]*$/{
    # If "111" comes first, print out both lines as is (with same line number).
    b
}
# If "222" comes first, print out in reverse order
s/^\([^\n]*\)\n\([^\n]*\)$/\2\n\1/
'
```

This has a bug suffering that does not handle more then 2 consecutive lines of `service_id` one after another, but `There are only maximum 2 consecutive lines that contain "service_id"` so should be fine. And the regexes need to be refined to more match OPs, but I hope that's not that hard to do. Also I did not care what happens if there is no `111` nor `222` in the input.

A cute oneliner:

```
sed '/service_id/!b; N;/service_id[^\n]*\n[^\n]*service_id/!{ /222/{ s/^/NONE/; }; b; }; /111[^\n]*\n[^\n]*$/b; s/^\([^\n]*\)\n\([^\n]*\)$/\2\n\1/'
```

[Tetsted on repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/IroncladAdmirableLanservers#main.sh)

Comment: I put all into a single line:  sed ' /service_id/!{ b } N; /service_id[^\n]*\n[^\n]*service_id/!{ /222/{ s/^/NONE/ } b } /111[^\n]*\n[^\n]*$/{ b } s/^\([^\n]*\)\n\([^\n]*\)$/\2\n\1/ '  and executed.  The result:  
sed: -e expression #1, char 17: extra characters after command

Comment: That's because you putted it on a single line... the `}` need a `;`. Well, you can't just "I did that and it breaks", yea, it does, dunno what you expect?

Comment: Works perfectly :). As info: The vote was recorded, but it isn't public because my rep isn't 15 yet.